# Test are passing and they shouldn't

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, tdd, mstest

**Before** I added `[Authorize]` filters for each controller, I created test cases and made them pass. Now I have added said filter on each controller's method but they still pass, but I think they shouldn't since there is no logged user. Am I not seeing something?

PS: I haven't mocked Identity 2.0

**Edit:**

Basically I'm mocking a repository, through the unit of work pattern. In my unit test, I get a reference to the `List` the mock repository uses, in order to test.

```
[TestMethod]
    public async Task CanCreateCustomerAndRedirectToDetails() {
        // Arrange
        Customer customer = NewCustomer(); // Gets a new customer that is NOT on the list
        CustomerCreateViewModel viewModel = Mapper.Map<CustomerCreateViewModel>(customer); // Maps to viewmodel

        // Act
        RedirectToRouteResult result = (RedirectToRouteResult) await Controller.Create(viewModel); // Sends to controller

        // Assert

        // Up to this point, Customers is the mock repository's list. so it should contain the new created customer since the controller should call the insert method
        // Normally, the assertion should pass. But after I implemented [Authorize] filter, I would expect the controller not to do anything (besides redirecting to login) and this test would fail
        Assert.IsNotNull(Customers.FirstOrDefault(e => e.ID == customer.ID));
        Assert.AreEqual("Details", result.RouteValues["action"].ToString());
    }
```

Comment: Depends entirely on what you're testing.  Can you show the method and the test?

Comment: Editted my question to explain my unit test

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing in your unit test which responds to or in any way examines the `Authorize` attribute.  Or any attribute.

Attributes don't actually change the behavior of the method.  They decorate the method in a way that other code (such as in a framework, like ASP.NET MVC) might recognize.  The `Authorize` attribute is used by the ASP.NET MVC framework.  But the attribute alone doesn't change the method.

MSTest doesn't use the `Authorize` attribute.  So if you want to test its presence on the method, you'd need to examine it in some way.  Though that shouldn't really be necessary.  The functionality of the framework is already very thoroughly tested by its vendor.

All your test needs to be testing is the functionality of the method, which it is.  You don't need to test the functionality of the ASP.NET Framework.

You *can* test attributes very effectively by unit testing the classes which define those attributes.  So if you, for example, created a custom attribute (let's call it `CustomAuthorize`) then you would have a class defining that attribute (`CustomAuthorizeAttribute`) and you could unit test that class, separately from unit testing your controllers.